# Java parsing line by pipe

Tags: java, regex, parsing, split, pipe

please, I have problem with parsing line in file by **pipe** (**|**) delimiter in **Java**.

I have this line:

```
4||AD3451059||||||||||||||||||||||1040374.670831981|739638.7683246896|50.11484423280666|14.460148189573438||||||
```

I'm trying it parse in Java using:

```
String[] params = line.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

But I also tried:

```
String[] params = line.split("\\|");
```

The line has 34 parameters (index 0 - 33) but array `params` has just 28 parameters (index 0 - 27).

```
System.out.println("Line: " + String.valueOf(i) + " has " + String.valueOf(params.length) + " parameters." );
```

outputs: Line: 17 has 28 parameters.

For example, this line works perfectly:

```
1||AD00000|CZ|Prague|19|Prague|3100|Prague|554782|||||||Street|489930|||||District||1048025.7908252006|751353.7683138615|50.032290186813704|14.31264367762477|0|0||false||
```

The line above has 34 parameters which is true. How it's possible please?

Is the possible, that after index 27 i have just **|** and nothing more to the of the line? How can I parse it regular please? Thank you very much

Best regards

Comment: It seems you want `line.split("\\|", -1)` to keep all trailing empty items, right?

Comment: YES! This works.... Yay, great :))) Thanks